# Change button background image using method in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

My code for Form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YAHTZEE
{
    public partial class GameMainWindow : Form
    {
        public GameMainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonRollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DiceManager dm = new DiceManager();
            dm.intDice_1_Roll();
            dm.intDice_2_Roll();
            dm.intDice_3_Roll();
            dm.intDice_4_Roll();
            dm.intDice_5_Roll();

            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            c1.buttonDice_1Manager();

        }
    }
}
```

My class for generating random number for all the dice.
This works perfectly fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YAHTZEE
{
    public class DiceManager
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        public int intDice_1_Roll()
        {
            int intDice_1 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            return intDice_1;
        }

        public int intDice_2_Roll()
        {
            int intDice_2 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            return intDice_2;
        }

        public int intDice_3_Roll()
        {
            int intDice_3 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            return intDice_3;
        }

        public int intDice_4_Roll()
        {
            int intDice_4 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            return intDice_4;
        }

        public int intDice_5_Roll()
        {
            int intDice_5 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            return intDice_5;
        }
    }
}
```

Class to change button background image.
This is where my problem is, the code works if I put it on my form but it does nothing when I make it a method on another class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using YAHTZEE.Properties;

namespace YAHTZEE
{
    class Class1 : GameMainWindow
    {
        public void buttonDice_1Manager()
        {
            DiceManager dm = new DiceManager();

            if (dm.intDice_1_Roll() == 1)
            {
                buttonDice_1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Dice1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

P.S. I want them to be separated because there are a lot of things to consider making my code very long.

Comment: Set your `buttonDice_1` acessibility to `protected`. You can change it in the properties via `Modifiers` property.

Comment: In `buttonRollDice_Click` you create a DiceManager and roll for each die and then create Class1 which creates another DiceManager and rolls the first die and changes the original first die if the new one is 1. Are you sure that makes sense? Also, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with the dice roll results. Your methods for getting a dice roll are all the same except for variable names. You could just have them all be one method. Just some things to consider.

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks. But it still does nothing

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I did create a method for each dice because I will add more codes for it. Class1 only checks what number each dice has it doesn't re-roll it's original value.

Comment: What he meant is that you're checking only for the first roll and only if it's equal to 1. Chances are that it will never be equal to that value so you wont see any changes.

Comment: But it is re-rolling from the looks of it. `dm.intDice_1_Roll()` will get a new random number. I guess the overall point I'm trying to make is that your code doesn't make sense conceptually.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad Oh lol I will try to change it it's just I can't make the button change it's background  using a method from another class

Comment: @m.rogalski I did changed the result always equal to 1 but it still won't change background image lol

Comment: If you change it to be... `public void buttonDice_1Manager()
        { buttonDice_1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Dice1; }` does it work?

Comment: Paste your `InitializeComponent()` contents, Maybe you've just disabled image as a background ?

Comment: @m.rogalski I put nothing but InitializeComponent()

Comment: @BlakeThingstad Nope

Comment: ... I meant click on `InitializeComponent()` inside `GameMainWindow` and hit `F12`, it should bring you to the implementation. Copy this and paste here in your question/

Answer (score 0):

In class1, try changing your method to:

```
public System.Drawing.Bitmap dice1Manager(int diceRoll)
{
    if(diceRoll == 1)
        return Properties.Resources.Dice1;
}
```

In your main class, change what you have to:

```
private void buttonRollDice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DiceManager dm = new DiceManager();
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();

    button_dice1.BackgroundImage = c1.dice1Manager(dm.intDice_1_Roll());

    dm.intDice_2_Roll();
    dm.intDice_3_Roll();
    dm.intDice_4_Roll();
    dm.intDice_5_Roll();
 }
```